# -Inf content in a Position Weight Matrix

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

What does it mean when I have -Inf content in some positions of a Position Weight Matrix?

I am using the seqLogo package. For plotting the seqLogo:

```
library(seqLogo)

seqLogo(weight_matrix, ic.scale=TRUE, xaxis=TRUE, yaxis=TRUE, xfontsize=15, yfontsize=15)
```

and I have:

> Error in seqLogo(weight_matrix, ic.scale = TRUE, xaxis = TRUE, yaxis =
>   TRUE, : Columns of PWM must add up to 1.0

Comment: I load a dataset of nucleobases in R and I want to create the Position Frequency Matrix and the Position Weight Matrix.
The problem is, that in the positions of Frequency Matrix where I have 0, in the PWM I have -Inf. 
I also want to make a seqLogo, so does -Inf prevent me to do this?

Comment: Because `log2(0/0.25)` is `-Inf`, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_weight_matrix) for more info.

Comment: Does -Inf prevent me from creating the seqLogo?
Because I got an error, and I am wondering if -Inf is the reason.

Comment: From the error it is obvious, column sum must be equal to 1, as it is sum of probabilities can't be more than 1.

Comment: Please see: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/228487).

Answer (score 1):

From the error it is obvious, column sum must be equal to 1. As it is sum of probabilities, which can't be more than 1. See example:

Below works fine, using example *m* matrix from *seqLogo* package:

```
library(seqLogo)

# get example matrix
mFile <- system.file("Exfiles/pwm1", package="seqLogo")
m <- read.table(mFile)

# check if all columns have sum of 1
colSums(m)
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 
#  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 

# plot, all great!
seqLogo(m)
```

Now, let's change one of the values, so that column sum is more than 1. This will give us error.

```
m[1, 1] <- 1

# check if all columns have sum of 1
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 
#  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 

seqLogo(m)
# Error in seqLogo(m) : Columns of PWM must add up to 1.0
```

---

**Other** reason could be that matrix values are already logged. If they are then convert them back to probabilities using:

```
plotMatrix <- 2 ^ weight_matrix * 0.25
```

then plot:

```
seqLogo(plotMatrix)
```

Comment: But my PWM already satisfies column sums to 1, why do I still get the same error?